# Adding log rotation to exsisting container without recreateing

Tags: docker

Docker logs are way too big with default configuration, and it's eating up my server space.

I know I can configure `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add something like this:

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "10"
  }
}
```

and restart Docker service. But it only works for NEW containers.

Is there a way to update log rotation configuration of exsisting container without recreating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change most container settings without recreating it (the list of available settings is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_update/)). I suggest you rather recreate containers with the new log policy because that is simpler and cleaner than the alternative, which is to configure [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) for these files: `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log`.